# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] } on kitkat android

Tags: android

I'm developing application where I've to select a folder from external storage and then I've to get its path which I later pass to fileobserver. everything is working fine. I'm using this code to select directory:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CODE);
```

and it gives me this interface:
[directory chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60hiY.jpg)

Problem: when I run app on KITKAT it gives me above mentioned exception. I've searched it over internet but could not figure out alternative for this. I just want to select directory and get its path on kikat.

Comment: That code does not select a directory. It selects a document tree. That may represent a filesystem directory, but it might not (e.g., Google Drive). If you need a directory, and you need it to work on API Level 19, [find a directory chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) was added in API 21 (Lollipop) - it does not exist on API 19 (Kitkat) devices and there is no equivalent for pre-API 21 devices.

You'll need to request the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and build your own file browser from scratch if you want to let users select a folder on Kitkat devices.

Comment: Ok! Do you know any good tutorial to do this or any reference to get it done because it seems to me lots of work.

Comment: It is a ridiculously large amount of work. I'd just limit that functionality to API 21+ devices (that is over [88.9% of devices](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/)).